# Find this function range $f(x)=\sqrt{2+\cos{x}+\sqrt{3}\sin{x}}+2\sqrt{2+\cos{x}-\sqrt{3}\sin{x}}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

let $x\in R$, find the following function range
$$f(x)=\sqrt{2+\cos{x}+\sqrt{3}\sin{x}}+2\sqrt{2+\cos{x}-\sqrt{3}\sin{x}}$$

since use wolfarmapha see:[wolf](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3D%5Csqrt%7B2%2B%5Ccos%7Bx%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%5Csin%7Bx%7D%7D%2B2%5Csqrt%7B2%2B%5Ccos%7Bx%7D-%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%5Csin%7Bx%7D%7D)

I Found no parsing value, but this is a test questions, I think should have good results, the possible problem is what happened to the software settings, lead to can't get the answer we need

Comment: Notice that:
\begin{align}
\cos(x)+\sqrt{3} \sin(x)&=2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sin(x) \right)= 2\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} \right)\cos(x)+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6} \right) \sin(x) \right)\\
&=2\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{6} \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Using $\cos2y=2\cos^2y-1$

$$2+\cos x+\sqrt3\sin x=2\left(1+\cos\left(x-\dfrac\pi3\right)\right)=4\cos^2\left(\dfrac x2-\dfrac\pi6\right)$$

$$2+\cos x-\sqrt3\sin x=2\left(1+\cos\left(x+\dfrac\pi3\right)\right)=4\cos^2\left(\dfrac x2+\dfrac\pi6\right)$$

Now $\sqrt{a^2}=\begin{cases} a &\mbox{if } a\ge0 \\-a & \mbox{if } a<0\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Using

$$
a \cos x \pm b \sin x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x \pm \arctan(b/a))
$$

we have

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2+\cos{x}+\sqrt{3}\sin{x}}+2\sqrt{2+\cos{x}-\sqrt{3}\sin{x}} = \sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{1+\cos(x+\pi/3))}+2\sqrt{1+\cos(x-\pi/3)}\right)$$

etc.